# Delphi program to HTTP request

Tags: delphi, httprequest, pascal

I want to HTTP request using Delphi program.

I used below code but i got error called **"Undeclared identifier : TIdHTTP"**

**I am new in Delphi.**

I request you to help me.

```
function PostExample: string;
var
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  lParamList.Add('id=1');

  lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    Result := TIdHTTP.Post('http://192.168.1.247:8001/test/test_api/', lParamList);
  finally
    lHTTP.Free;
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;

Procedure http;
begin
PostExample();
end;
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken, `TIdHTTP` comes out of the [Indy](https://www.indyproject.org/) library.

Comment: Have you learnt about units yet, and how to use them with the `use` statment?

Comment: It appears you would benefit from reading the articles in this [Delphi reference](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/Delphi_Reference)

Answer (score 5):

`TIdHTTP` is a component of [Indy](https://www.indyproject.org), which is pre-installed in the IDE.

If you are making a visual GUI project, you can simply drop the `TIdHTTP` component onto your Form/Frame/DataModule at design-time.

Otherwise, to use it solely in code only, you need to add the `IdHTTP` unit to your `uses` clause, and your project needs to require the `IndySystem#`, `IndyCore#`, and `IndyProtocols#` packages, where # is the [Package Version number](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions) for your particular version of Delphi.

Also, there are a couple of minor bugs in your code. `Post()` is not a `static` method of the `TIdHTTP` class, so you need to use your `lHTTP` variable to call it. Also, `lParamList.Free` should be in its own `try..finally` block.

```
uses
  ..., IdHTTP, Dialogs;

function PostExample: string;
var 
  lHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  lParamList: TStringList;
begin
  lParamList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    lParamList.Add('id=1');
    lHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
    try
      Result := lHTTP.Post('http://192.168.1.247:8001/test/test_api/', lParamList);
    finally
      lHTTP.Free;
    end;
  finally
    lParamList.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure http;
begin
  ShowMessage(PostExample());
end;
```

Comment: Where i have to put IndySystem#,IndyCore#,IndyProtocols# ?
Is there any other way to http request in delphi without using form?

Comment: @BhavinS. Your **project**, not your **code**, needs to include references to those packages. Otherwise, if you don't want to depend on any 3rd party libraries, you can always just use OS provided APIs instead. Like WinInet/WinHTTP on Windows.

Comment: @RemyLeabeau. Thanks for suggestion. 
Is there any way to Http Request without using Indy, Because now Indy website is on Update so i could not download it.

Comment: @BhavinS. "*without using Indy*" - I already addressed that in my previous comment. "*I could not download it*" - why not? Although the Indy website is being redesigned, the download links do work.

Comment: @RemyLeabeau. I have downloaded the Indy library.
I have package in my project "IndyCore10", "IndyProtocols10", "IndySystem10".
Still i am getting same error. "Undeclared identifier : TIdHTTP".
Actually I ran my program from Altium Designer.
Altium Designer provide the Delphi scripting for automation.
I dont have Delphi IDE.

Comment: @BhavinS. There are no "...10" packages in Indy. I can't help you with Altium. But if it is just scripting, you are not going to be able to use indy in it. Indy officially only supports Delphi/C++Builder, FreePascal/Lazarus, and DotNet. Looking at Altium's documentation, it doesn't support the use of 3rd party Delphi packages, or even writing custom classes. But it does allow you to write custom extension via a separate SDK. So it *might* be able to compile an addon in Delphi that uses `TIdHTTP` internally, and then access that addon in Altium scripts. But you say you don't have Delphi...